# Map loading in Terminal but (image not found in Rviz)

Tags: rviz

ubuntu 18.04 Rviz

my current launch file

```
<arg name="robot_namespace" default="/"/>

<!-- Load URDF model -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find limo_description)/urdf/limo_ackerman.xacro'
    robot_namespace:=$(arg robot_namespace)" />

<!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
<rosparam file="$(find limo_gazebo_sim)/config/limo_ackerman_control.yaml" command="load"/>

<!-- Load controllers -->
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen"
      args="limo_state_controller limo_fl_steering_hinge_controller limo_fr_steering_hinge_controller"/>

<!-- Robot state publisher for URDF visualization -->
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

<!-- Joint State Publisher for the wheels -->
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="use_gui" value="false"/> <!-- Set to true if you want to use the GUI -->
</node>

<!-- Use robot pose ekf to provide odometry -->
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom" />
    <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_link" />
    <remap from="imu_data" to="imu" />
</node>

<!-- Launch AMCL for localization -->
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find limo_bringup)/param/amcl_params_omni.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0" />
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
    <param name="map_file" value="$(find limo_bringup)/maps/mylimomap.yaml" />
</node>

<!-- Launch RViz with the amcl.rviz configuration -->
<node name="rviz_amcl" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find limo_bringup)/rviz/amcl.rviz" />
```

Currently when running :

rosrun map_server map_server mylimomap.yaml[ INFO] [1698894029.234616479]: Loading map from image "mylimomap.pgm

It shows that:

[ INFO] [1698893480.853439381]: Loading map from image "mylimomap.pgm"
[ INFO] [1698893480.928262434]: Read a 4000 X 4000 map @ 0.050 m/cell

but Rviz shows that"image not found"  why is that so

Link of Rviz to show the issue
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xge3uHC-lcusR8IcR_xOy6k5rPaH5BvI/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, to clarify: the problem occurs only when you execute the command rosrun map_server map_server mylimomap.yaml, and not from the launch file, correct?

Try this checklist:

1. Source your ROS distribution.
2. Confirm that both .yaml and .pgm files reside in the same directory.
3. Verify the filename specified inside the .yaml matches the .pgm filename.
4. Execute:rosrun map_server map_server path_to_your_map_folder/mylimomap.yaml
5. Make sure the topic for the map is set to /map